# start service over systemd as non-root to bind port 80, 443

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, port, systemd, service

im running tomcat on my ubuntu 18.04 headless server as root. Like in apache or nginx you can start a service as non-root with systemd and only root will start the master process to bind the ports 80 & 443. So i will using the same start process like apache&nginx for my tomcat. After adding user and group as tomcat (no superuser) and create tomcat.service, what i need config too ???

i would be very thankfull if somebody cans helps me out.

blackbeard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most of the services is configured as default on the port >1024. There is several reasons for that...

The way you are trying to focus is possible but it may cause some future steps requiring (at least for a while a root access to do the changes)... But I cannot say it would be wrong ;).

Please don't down vote me for the alternative solution (as it is not directly the answer for the question). What about keep service on default >1024 port and setup reverse proxy (haproxy, nginx, apache http, etc. - whatever you are familiar with) to accept the connection on 80 and / or 443 and conditionally (SNI) or unconditionally proxy the traffic to application default port? The side effect would be that you can "share" 80/443 between more services on the host.

Comment: its a stable to run tomcat, reverse proxy and mysql on the same server ?

Comment: Depends on load. In general yes but in case of high load i would think abut moving db out... with normal small-medium app it may be ok.